# Waveshare e-Ink 2.9 and Heltec WIFI LoRa 32 V2

Tags: esp32, e-ink

I’m trying to connect mit LoRa-ESP32 with an ePaper-Display from Waveshare.

Therefore I’m using the GxEPD2 Library, but this does not work (with the library givven by waveshare the display works, but the usage is disgusting...).

Know, I don’t know if the Libraries and includes are not correct or the pin-setup. Maybe some of you already connected such a display to that ESP.

My Pin-Setup is:

```
GND -> GND
3.3 -> VCC
DIN -> 27 LORA_MOSI
CLK -> 5 LORA_SCK, VSPI_CSO
DC -> 15 OLED_SCL (I’m not using the onboard OLED)
CS -> 4 OLED_SDA
RST -> 16 OLED_RST
BUSY -> 36
```

Is this Pin-Setup useable? Do you have ideas or working includes for the Heltec ESP and GxEPD2?

Thanks
SUT

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with it